# how to set limit into log_message in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have some issue on set limit into `log_message` in CodeIgniter, 
I am trying to complete it using

```
$config['log_file_permissions'] = 0644;
```

This is not working.

After 600 lines of the log message, I want to create new files. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: CI doesn't have that kind of feature yet. And don't think other Frameworks support this too *After 600 lines of the log message, I want to create new files*. **But in CI you can limit what to be written in log**

Comment: Hi Subrat, welcome to SO! Your question is a little broad at the moment, typically questions stating "This is not working" without any kind of explanation of what you are hoping to achieve versus what you actually achieve are closed as off topic. I would ask you to review this and flesh out your answer a little more: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion @AbdullaNilam, Can you please help me to achive this.

Answer (score 0):

Q - After 600 lines of the log message, I want to create new files.
A - CI doesn't have this kind of feature yet

---

### For Future Reference

> **CI can categorize which of your data to be written in log files. (ex: Error Message, Debug Message, Informational ...)**

[User Guide Link](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/application/config/config.php#L194-L216)

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Error Logging Threshold
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You can enable error logging by setting a threshold over zero. The
| threshold determines what gets logged. Threshold options are:
|
|   0 = Disables logging, Error logging TURNED OFF
|   1 = Error Messages (including PHP errors)
|   2 = Debug Messages
|   3 = Informational Messages
|   4 = All Messages
|
| You can also pass an array with threshold levels to show individual error types
|
|   array(2) = Debug Messages, without Error Messages
|
| For a live site you'll usually only enable Errors (1) to be logged otherwise
| your log files will fill up very fast.
|
*/
$config['log_threshold'] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could extend `system/core/Log.php` and override the `write_log($level, $msg)` method.

The main task will be changing the scheme for naming log files.

The `CI_Log` class uses the following as the name of the current file.

```
$filepath = $this->_log_path.'log-'.date('Y-m-d').'.'.$this->_file_ext;
```

Which basically means there is one log file for any given day. But your desired functionality could result in multiple files on a day. I do not have an elegant way to address this part of the problem. The answer will depend on how you wish to name additional log files. Appending a "_1", "_2", "_n" to `date('Y-m-d')` is one possibility. Again, I don't offer a way to determine the correct "sub-day" version to use.

However, once you have figured out what the current files is, determining the number of lines in the file is trivial.

```
$file="current_log_file_name";
$linecount = 0;
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
while(!feof($handle)){
  $line = fgets($handle);
  $linecount++;
}

fclose($handle);
```

If `$linecount > 600` then create a new file, else use "current_log_file_name".